# Admob ad disturbs elements inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-button, android-relativelayout

I've successfully placed an ad at the bottom of the layout and it works nice.

My layout has four buttons, but the add disturbs all of them, raising them up. I'd like the buttons to be centered in the layout and the add at the bottom, without modifying the position of the buttons.

Here is the code of my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5943098653743528/9263521291"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pers"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/pers"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/university"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pers"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/university"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/university"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/help"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/information"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/help"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/information"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton5" />
```

Hope there's a solution! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FrameLayout` to layer the advertisement over your main UI components. `FrameLayout` stacks elements in the order they are introduced.

In this case, the `RelativeLayout` will be the first layer, and the advertisement will be stacked on top of it. I use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to position the advertisement at the bottom of the parenting `FrameLayout`.

Also, your buttons are aligning to the top of their parenting `RelativeLayout`, which is what's bringing them to the top of the view. Remove that for the `RelativeLayout` `android:gravity="center"` to work.

Hope this helps!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pers"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/pers"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/university"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pers"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/university"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/university"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/help"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/information"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/help"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/information"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton5" />
</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_gravity="bottom
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5943098653743528/9263521291"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</FrameLayout>
```